# How to define an environment variable that can be automatically used in multiple npm scripts?

Tags: bash, shell, npm, npm-scripts, process-substitution

Consider the following npm scripts.

```
$ npm run
available via `npm run-script`:
  make
    OUTPUT=dist/main.js bash -c 'elm make src/Main.js --output=$0 $1'
  make:dev
    npm run make -- '$OUTPUT' --debug
  make:prod
    npm run make -- '>(npm run uglify -- $OUTPUT)' --optimize
  uglify
    uglifyjs --compress 'pure_funcs="F2,F3,F4,F5,F6,F7,F8,F9,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8,A9",pure_getters,keep_fargs=false,unsafe_comps,unsafe' | uglifyjs --mangle --output=
```

I'd like to use it as follows:

```
$ npm run make -- '$OUTPUT' '--debug'


> experiment@0.1.0 experiment /Users/Adit/experiment
> OUTPUT=dist/main.js bash -c 'elm make src/Main.js --output=$0 $1' '$OUTPUT' '--debug'
```

This would correctly create the debug build of the Elm application. However, this is not what happens. Instead of using single quotes, `npm run` uses double quotes:

```
$ npm run make -- '$OUTPUT' '--debug'


> experiment@0.1.0 experiment /Users/Adit/experiment
> OUTPUT=dist/main.js bash -c 'elm make src/Main.js --output=$0 $1' "$OUTPUT" "--debug"
```

Due to this the output is not what I expect it to be. What's the best way to resolve this issue without writing a custom shell script? I want to use the `OUTPUT` variable in two different commands. However, I only want to define it in one place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem as follows.

```
{
    "config": {
        "input": "src/Main.elm",
        "output": "dist/main.js"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "make": "elm make $npm_package_config_input --output $npm_package_config_output",
        "make:dev": "npm run make -- --debug",
        "make:prod": "npm run make -- --optimize",
        "postmake:prod": "uglifyjs $npm_package_config_output --compress 'pure_funcs=\"F2,F3,F4,F5,F6,F7,F8,F9,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8,A9\",pure_getters,keep_fargs=false,unsafe_comps,unsafe' | uglifyjs --mangle --output=$npm_package_config_output"
    }
}
```

Hence, if you have a configuration variables that you'd like to use in multiple npm scripts, you can add them to the `config` dictionary of `package.json`. After that, you can access them as environment variables in the npm scripts via the name `$npm_package_config_<name>` where `<name>` is the name of your config variable.

I also used a post script instead of process substitution to uglify the output of the Elm compiler. Doing so was overall less of a hassle than using process substitution via `bash -c`.

Finally, you can run `make`, `make:dev`, or `make:prod` for different builds. The first one is a regular build. The second one is a development build with the Elm debugging tools. The third one is a regular build which is optimized and minified for production use.

Comment: Interesting, I thought you wanted to _"**pass** literal arguments to npm scripts?"_. and not  hardcode them as such.

Comment: This is an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). My actual problem was that I wanted to define `output` only once and use it across multiple commands. In my first attempt I tried to define the variable `OUTPUT` in the `make` script and then define how to use this variable in the `make:dev` and `make:prod` scripts. However, this didn't work because `npm run` replaced single quotes with double quotes. Hence, I asked about how to pass literal arguments to npm scripts. Sorry about that. I'll edit my question and ask about my real problem.

Comment: Sure, no worries. I understand that cross-platform is not a requirement in this case, however it's worth noting that when referencing environment variables, e.g.`$npm_package_config_output` using windows `cmd.exe` the syntax becomes `%npm_package_config_output%` _(note leading and trailing `%` instead of dollar `$` prefix)_ - [cross-var](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-var) can help in such a scenario whereby cross-platform is a requirement.

Comment: @RobC I always wanted to hardcode the value of the variables. However, I wanted to use the variable in different ways in different commands. Hence, I was passing arguments to the npm scirpts which described what to do with the hardcoded variables. However, the code was being executed instead of being passed literally to bash. Hope that makes more sense.

Comment: Use `cross-var` for cross-platform environment variables. Thank you for that information.